# asset-transfer-basic blows up with "SendTransaction failed: orderers is nil"

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-go

I am trying to run asset-transfer-basic sample program from hyperledger 2.2 (I am using the GO sample programs) My test network is up -- I am able to interact with it by doing "peer chaincode invoke" and exercising different contract methods -- including InitLedger.

However, when trying to run assetTransfer.go program, it blows up when doing:

```
result, err := contract.SubmitTransaction("InitLedger")
```

The error message is:
failed to evaluate transaction: Failed to submit: CreateAndSendTransaction failed: SendTransaction failed: orderers is nil

Any clues?  THank you

Answer (score 0):

Your length of orderers is zero. You have to set at least one orderer for this process in your fabric-sdk-go code.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in the Go SDK.  In its current form, the asset-transfer-basic app, the Go flavor, simply does not work.